# what is causing to play song on this blog

Tags: html

I am trying to understand as why on this blog

http://mysiddhashram.blogspot.com/

each time I refresh it starts playing sound.
I tried to read the source code but I am not clear as what is causing the sound to play.
Can any one help me to understand as which lines are causing the sound to be played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash scripts on the page are playing sound. You can identify them in source by `<object>` and `<embed>` tags.

Comment: thanks for the hint I got it , twameva.swf is the sound I was searching